# plot horizontal bars to Highchart price chart

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, jsfiddle

I am in trouble of adding multiple series into a stock price chart using Highcharts. I have data coming out each day that i would like to add to charts as horizontal bars. Example here (eurusd, using metatrader): http://tinypic.com/r/2uqhb4m/8

thanks a lot for any help.

Sten

Comment: Hi there.  First of all for stock charts HighStock is better. Im not sure what you want to achieve, maybe this? http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I want to plot currencys and other instruments (commodities, stock indexes, not individual stocks). I want to plot option levels into price charts, for every day. As horizontal bars, size is based on the volume. Every new day it starts over based on the data coming in. The pic i attached you can see those green and red horizontal bars with different sizes. i don't know how to get them to price chart

Comment: Unfortunately you can't plot horizontal bars in Highstock. In fact, you can draw or horizontal bars or vertical (just limitation in Highcharts) ones. Would be easier solution use separate `line` series? With data like this: `[ [from_1, value_1], [to_1, value_1], [to_1 + 1, null], [from_2, value_2], [to_2, value_2] ]` - so each two segments will be split by null-point.